# Ember.Handlebars.compile returns code instead of handlebars output

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a view that looks like this:

```
App.StarRatingView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: function() {
        return new Ember.Handlebars.compile('test')
    }
})
```

This is supposed to insert `test` in the page, but instead it inserts the definition of the `compile()` function:

```
function (context, options) { options = options || {}; var result = templateSpec.call(container, Handlebars, context, options.helpers, options.partials, options.data); var compilerInfo = container.compilerInfo || [], compilerRevision = compilerInfo[0] || 1, currentRevision = Handlebars.COMPILER_REVISION; if (compilerRevision !== currentRevision) { if (compilerRevision < currentRevision) { var runtimeVersions = Handlebars.REVISION_CHANGES[currentRevision], compilerVersions = Handlebars.REVISION_CHANGES[compilerRevision]; throw "Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the current runtime. "+ "Please update your precompiler to a newer version ("+runtimeVersions+") or downgrade your runtime to an older version ("+compilerVersions+")."; } else { // Use the embedded version info since the runtime doesn't know about this revision yet throw "Template was precompiled with a newer version of Handlebars than the current runtime. "+ "Please update your runtime to a newer version ("+compilerInfo[1]+")."; } } return result; }
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't expect a function. This should do the trick

```
App.StarRatingView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('test')
})
```

Or even better:

```
App.StarRatingView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'test'
})
```

Ember will now render the view using the given template name.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the `template` property to the contents of the compiled output:

```
App.StarRatingView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('test')
})
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uYOvUWU/1/edit

Also see the emberjs docs on using [templates in views](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/inserting-views-in-templates/)